# How make Thread - notify()/notifyAll() private

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a way, to prevent a Thread from call `notify()` / `notifyAll()`?
And then, it will be possible to call `notify`'s just inside the Class.

A kind of `notify`'s method private. (a kind of, we know, we can't)

Here some code, must attention on `OtherThread` in `synchronized`, to what I want to prevent:

```
public class MainThread {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Main Thread");
        X x = new X();
        x.start();

        OtherThread y = new OtherThread(x);
        y.start();


        synchronized (x){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Waiting");
            x.wait();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": Now I'm running");

    }

}

class X extends Thread{


    public void run(){
        // setting thread name
        Thread.currentThread().setName("X");


        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*5); // 5 seconds here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (this){
            this.notify();// I want only notify/notifyAll inside X to be possible
            System.out.println("Notified from "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Thread");
        }

    }
}

class OtherThread extends Thread{
    Thread t;

    public OtherThread(Thread x){ // pass the X thread to this thread
        this.t = x;
    }

    public void run(){
        // setting thread name
        Thread.currentThread().setName("OtherThread");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*1); // 1 second here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (t){
            t.notify(); // prevent this. To can't call notify from outside class X.
            System.out.println("Notified from "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Thread");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is that you can't. I mean, you can't change `notify` / `wait` visibility at all (they are set to public for all objects)

However, I think visibility is not the right tool for you. You are using the instance of X as a monitor over which you are waiting / notifying. The issue is that you are sharing that X thread to other threads as well, for other non specified reasons. So everybody can pontentially call wait/notify too.

What I suggest is using another object as monitor (instead of the instance of X) and sharing that object only between the ones that need to interact with it. Something like:

```
public class MainThread {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Main Thread");
        Object monitor = new Object();

        X x = new X(monitor);
        x.start();

        OtherThread y = new OtherThread(x);
        y.start();


        synchronized (monitor){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Waiting");
            monitor.wait();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": Now I'm running");

    }

}

class X extends Thread{

    private Object monitor;

    public X(Object monitor) {
      this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    public void run(){
        // setting thread name
        Thread.currentThread().setName("X");


        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*5); // 5 seconds here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (this.monitor){
            this.monitor.notify();// I want only notify/notifyAll inside X to be possible
            System.out.println("Notified from "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Thread");
        }

    }
}

class OtherThread extends Thread{
    Thread t;

    public OtherThread(Thread x){ // pass the X thread to this thread
        this.t = x;
    }

    public void run(){
        // setting thread name
        Thread.currentThread().setName("OtherThread");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*1); // 1 second here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (t){
            t.notify(); // this will work, but it wont do anything.
            System.out.println("Notified from "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Thread");
        }
    }

}
```

Also, and only has a plus, I recommend you to look at more advanced ways to synchronize this. Instead of just sharing an Object to use its monitor you could create a `Semaphore` (or a `CountDownLatch`) which are more powerful and more semantically clear (and this is what I like about them).

**** Edit ****

Also, a minor suggestion. `Thread.currentThread().setName("X")` can actually can be changed by `this.setName("X")` since your object IS the thread and knows itself (you can't do that on the main thread though). However I propose to remove that altogether since `Thread` class exposes a constructor that allows you to set that name on beforehand, so instead of doing what you are doing you can:

```
class X extends Thread {

    public X() {
            super("X")
    }

    public void run(){
            try {
            ...
        }
    }

    class OtherThread extends Thread{
        Thread t;

        public OtherThread(Thread x){ // pass the X thread to this thread
            super("OtherThread");
            this.t = x;
        }

        public void run(){
            try {
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the currentThread.setName. I forgot that IS a Thread. lol.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent any piece of code from calling `notify` because it is a public method of `Object`, and a subclass cannot reduce the visibility of an inherited method or field.

Comment: I would add that both methods are `final` so you cannot overriding them neither.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a wrapper class that has a `Thread` member field, and not provide access to `notify()` & `notifyAll()` methods...

```
public class MyThreadWrapper { 
    private final Thread myThread;     

    public MyThreadWrapper(Runnable r) {
        myThread = new Thread(r);
    }

    //notice we haven't expose notify/notifyAll...

}
```

now your main would create the thread with:

```
MyThreadWrapper myLimitedThread = new MyThreadWrapper(someRunnable);
```

Comment: What ?! Not `exposing` the method does not make them disappear... They are still available from the `Object` class which is extended by every class.

Comment: I'm studying the Java Concurrency API. Is much more flexible. Maybe using the Lock object... I will study. Your answer is good and will solve the problem very easy. Tnx

Comment: @ortis of course it doesn't make them dissapear - nothing does.  The point is they are not available to anyone who is a client of this API....

Comment: @Amir Afghani yes, they are. What could prevent them to be available to a user of the API ?

Comment: @Ortis , you are correct, but the notifys methods of the wrapper class only will be exposed, not the notifys of wrapped class. You can call the notifys of the wrapper class and it will take no effect

Comment: Well, if you follow my example above, I'd like to see how you could call them using the described approach...

Comment: @ThufirHawat I did not provide a notify method on the wrapper.  I challenge you to use my example and call notify from outside of the class!

Answer (score 0):

wait and notify/notifyAll belong in Object class and public method, anyone who got access to that object can call those method.

Keypoint here is access to object, if you want only certain class to have access to certain object wait and notify/notifyAll, then you need to encapsulate that object to that class, donot return that object to outside world.

```
class X {
    private Object lock;

    public void someMethod() {
        //lock.wait();
        //lock.notify();
    }
}
```

Not sure what you trying to do, But if you trying to synchronize access to shared object across different thread there are many structure available depend upon the specific problem.

- Blocking Queue
- FutureTask
  etc